# How can I obtain an instance of a prototype UICollectionViewCell so that I can have variable sized collection view cells?

Tags: ios, layout, size, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make UICollectionViewCells whose widths change depending on its contents. I found an excellent tutorial on this topic: [Variable-Sized Items in UICollectionView](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/08/variable-sized-items-in-uicollectionview/) but leaves the reader wondering when the technique is applied **to Storyboards**:

> An alternative – and in some aspects more convenient – method is to use the collection view in a storyboard. There the cell prototype would be positioned not in a separate XIB file, but right in the structure hierarchy of the collection view. Exploring how to get a sizing cell there is left as an exercise for the reader.

The tutorial itself uses XIB's but it's not clear how you could obtain a `sizingCell`, as the author called it, from  a Storyboard.

Comment: This is the exactly problem I meet now, any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your Custom layout or flow layout conform to the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout Protocol`  and implement the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

Then return the size that you want the item to be.

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView%3alayout%3asizeForItemAtIndexPath):

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not the answer. If you look at the blog, I'm seeking a way to use a prototype cell to produce the return value for `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious way I can see to accomplish this, unfortunately, is to make separate Xibs for all your cells and register them with the collection view manually yourself.

Then you can also use the `UINib` instances to instantiate a cell for item sizing.

```
UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([JDPCell class])
                             bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib
      forCellWithReuseIdentifier:JDPCellReuseIdentifier];

id cell = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
self.prototypeCells[JDPCellReuseIdentifier] = cell;
```

Then later on

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString * reuseIdentifier = ...;
    UICollectionViewCell * cell = self.prototypeCells[reuseIdentifier];
    [cell updateConstraints];
    return cell.frame.size;
}
```

Comment: If your cell has IBOutlet, How do you pass the owner ?

Comment: you should rely on other mechanisms to connect your cells to objects outside the xib. E.g. send a message down the responder chain or use a delegate that you set in `-cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

I think we can get a new cell programmatically, then add the same subview and constraint.
But it's just a bypass, any one has a better idea?